# Wordpress custom field if else for showing data

Tags: wordpress

In my theme I have custom field 'ext_url'. Now I want to get post url If I don't add 'ext_url' custom field.

I tried

```
<?php if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ext_url', true)): ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php the_permalink(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

When I don't add custom field, it is showing post URL. But, when I add custom field it is showing blank. Any Solutions?

Update: I've found a code

```
<?php 
    $url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'ext_url', true); 

    if ($url) {
        echo "<p><a href='$url'>External URL</a></p>";
    }
?>
```

but, it is working for showing custom field. How can i add else function here? Sorry, I am not experienced in PHP.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. It sounds like it's doing what you want. Do you want the opposite to happen? Or you don't want it to **show** the URL? If it's the second, then you may need to use [`get_permalink`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink) instead of the_permalink.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I want "If I add custom field it will show custom field data & If I don't add custom field it will show post permalink"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to display the data from the custom field, you should add a line to echo the results.

```
<?php
$ext_url = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ext_url', true );

if ( $ext_url ) {
    echo $ext_url;
} else {
    the_permalink();
}
?>
```